# How to script a google search without google license key?

Tags: python, perl, api, search

I'm looking at 'pygoogle' python library for google search, call from my python script. But google doesn't give out license key anymore, and looks like pygoogle needs license key to work.

Does anyone have suggestions of libraries to use for scripting web searches? Languages doesn't matter. It can be in python, perl, lisp, forth, or whatever. Of course, it needs to get around the license key issue.

Or, would yahoo, excite, or any other sites provide apis allow scripting searches for free?

Any comments are welcomed. I'm new on web searches.

Thanks.

Jay

Comment: Pygoogle is very old, the latest release is dated 2004; and I tried it three years ago and it wasn't working well anyway. I believe there are other mechanisms to use now to search with google, look at their API page.

Answer (score 10):

They don't give out keys for the SOAP API anymore, because [that's deprecated](http://code.google.com/apis/soapsearch/). But you can use their [AJAX API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/), which is now the preferred interface. You can get a developer key [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/key.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your question made me look.

- Yahoo! now offers a new search service called [BOSS](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/boss/) which looks very interesting.
- Microsoft offers access via the [Bing API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251056.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

in case you are still looking - this is how (with ajax api in python): http://dcortesi.com/2008/05/28/google-ajax-search-api-example-python-code/